# Reflection class is not found but no exception is thrown

Tags: php, reflection

Okay, situation is quite simple: I have class (named Edam) from where I want create new reflection instances, like this:

```
public static function getClass($className) {
    try {
        $refl = new \ReflectionClass("classes\\$className");
        return $refl->newInstance();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e);
    }
}
```

I'm using the above function in a other class like this:

```
    $test = Edam::getClass("SomethingThatDoesntExist");
```

Problem is that I can't catch the exception (nothing gets printed to output) which I think should be thrown in this case. Catching the exception is important so that I can notify the user that the requested class doesn't exist.

Comment: What's up with your backslashes?

Comment: I'm using custom namespaces. Backslash is the way for calling PHP's native classes

Comment: Gotcha, been a few years since I touched PHP :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in spl_autoload_register(), it killed execution when the file wasn't found. Added the following file check which worked nicely:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($className) {
    $path = str_replace("\\", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . ".php";
    if (file_exists($path))
        require_once($path);
});
```